# Run multiple subprocesses in parallel - python 2.7

Tags: python, linux, networking, subprocess, ping

The script shown below is my attempt at pinging multiple network namespaces using python 2.7 running on Linux (Fedora) OS.

**Current status and problem**:

When I run this file; the ping from elem1 (namespace) gets stored in a file called results.txt.
But, I can't seem to get the loop to come back around and ping elem2, elem3, ... elemN

**Attempted Fixes**:

I tried killing the process using "kill -9 p.pid" (as shown) in the hope that this would kill the process and then a new process could be created on next iteration of the loop. However this is not the case!
I've checked the documentation ( https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html ) and tried several different permutations of kill(), terminate(), removing shell=True etc... but to no avail.

```
import time
import os
import signal
import subprocess    

IP_ADDR="192.168.1.1"    

def main():
arry =["elem1", "elem2", "elem3", "elem4", "elem5", "elem6", "elem7"]  array of network namespaces's to ping

        with open('results.txt', 'a+') as outfile:
            for elem in arry:
                command = "ip netns exec {0} ping {1}".format(elem, IP_ADDR)
                outfile.write("\n\nPinging {}\n".format(elem))
                p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=outfile)
                command_kill = "kill -9 {}".format(p.pid)
                time.sleep(2) #wait 5 seconds
                p.kill()
        outfile.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**My Questions**:

(1) Can someone explain what the code is doing here?

(2) Can you suggest a means to achieve my aforementioned goal?

Thank you

Comment: The process already runs in the background. The only thing keeping all of the pings from running at once is your call to `time.sleep` followed by `p.kill`. It's quite likely `kill -9` prevents the process from properly writing its output before the OS forces it to exit.

Comment: Thanks @chepner, as suggested I removed the lines command time.sleep(2) and p.kill(). The output file now displays Pinging elem1 - elem7 and then spits out ping results sequentially. I was hoping it would do as follows: Pinging elem1... [insert elem1 ping results here] Pinging elem2... [insert elem2 ping results here], ... Pinging elem7... [insert elem7ping results here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along with the modifications mentioned by @chepner, you can try to use `subprocess.call()` instead of `subprocess.Popen()`. The latter method is not blocking and this causes all the commands to be executed simultaneously. However, `call()` is blocking and therefore your script will wait until the pinging is finished before entering next iteration of the loop. This will cause the output of your commands to be in sequential order and not interleaving.

If you need to execute the commands in parallel, I would suggest to write the outputs into different files and combine them after all commands are finished.

Edit: I have no particular experience in this area, but I guess the termination issue is related to the `ping` command only. Check the manual page here: https://linux.die.net/man/8/ping. In our case, we need to ping the destination X times. This is specified by using parameter `-c X`, where X defines the number of packets to be sent. This parameter can be also combined with parameter `-w / -W` which specify the timeout limit for the ping command. Take a look at some examples: https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/11/ping-tutorial-13-effective-ping-command-examples/

Comment: Thanks @sikr. I have modified the code to call subprocess.call as opposed to subprocess.Popen. The only issue I have with this is that it will ping the first namespace indefinitely. I basically want to ping the elem1 network namespace X number of times then elem2 X number of times, then elem3 X number of times... How do you suggest I stop the ping after X iterations. NOTE: I am using the following command to execute pings: ip netns elemX ping 192.268.x.y

Comment: Thnaks @sikr_ This worked. To clarify for future readers the solution appears as follows:                                                                    command = "ip netns exec {0} ping -c 3 -w 5 {1}".format(elem1, IP_ADDR)                                                                                                                                                     p = subprocess.call(command, stdout=outfile, shell=True)